# Cannot mount one usb disc, although other mounts automatically after 12.10 upgrade

Tags: 12.10, usb

Since upgrading to 12.10, switching on or attempting to mount one of my usb hard drives gives this error message:

Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdg1: Command-line `mount
"/mnt/usb-ST350041_8AS_60CAFFFFFFFF-0:0-part1"' exited with non-zero exit
status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdg1,
           missing codepage or helper program, or other error
           In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
           dmesg | tail  or so

*dmesg | tail gives (inter alia):*

[ 1080.727830]  sdg: sdg1
[ 1080.732003] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1081.383633] FAT-fs (sdg1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or
missing value
[ 1871.160973]  sdg: sdg1

The drive cannot be mounted, but is recognized by the system as a "place". I am not a technical bod; I cannot take this further myself and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found the answer for the topic starter, also I had to experience it myself.
According to kernel blogs there is a strange behavior then using vfat with "x-gvfs-show" option. Now it can be solved by removing this option for vfat partition.
The option is used **only** to show device shortcut in Gnome and Unity then this one is mounted in a location **different** than "/media". So there is a way to configure vfat to be mounted under "/media" and to remove "x-gvfs-show" option from mount options (Can be easily done via Disks utility). Works very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with the file system on the device.  You might be able to force the mount as read-only for the purpose of backing up your data, which I highly recommend:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdg1 /mnt -t vfat -o ro
```

where the device is /dev/sdg as in your example above.

You will now find the files on this device until /mnt off the root file system.  Copy the files to another device or the hard drive, then you would be better off deleting even the partition table (not just the partitions) and starting from scratch with this device.

If you are not sure which is the correct device name to use type

```
blkid
```

to get a list of devices attached to the system (including hard drives, so be careful)

Comment: _Yes_, and thank you for that helpful advice. However, it does not explain why when running 12.10 from a live DVD, the same usb drive mounts up perfectly normally, just like the other one which has caused no trouble. That fact leads me to believe the trouble lies with the upgraded 12.10 rather than a corrupted file system on the usb disc. Am I right?