# vfat partition cannot be mounted with x-gvfs-show option

Tags: partitioning, mount

Got a problem with my laptop manufacturer's partition. It's FAT32-formatted and fails under same curcumstances as for topic starter at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218702/cannot-mount-one-usb-disc-although-other-mounts-automatically-after-12-10-upgra). **It seems like vfat got a problem working with x-gvfs-show parameter**.
Also, I seek for more "painless" solution then "format-and-refill", because this one is created by the manufacturer and (as far as I know) got specific structure adapted for BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, there's a problem with both `x-gvfs-show` and `x-gvfs-name` flags on the mount utility.

There's currently an [open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1011257) and, as suggested on that thread, until the dependencies are updated on Canonical's end, a workaround is to try and manually upgrade the package `util-linux` to 2.21+ in order to support the `x-gvfs` options.