# Mounting VFAT SD card on Ubuntu 14.04 not possible w/ x-gvfs-show option?

Tags: 14.04, mount, filesystem, sd-card

*[Ubuntu 14.04.3  x86_64]*

I have a 128MB SD card that I want to use as a read-only tripwire binary and database volume. Using UDisks I reformatted (complete wipe) that card with FAT-16 bit version as lone FAT option, along with NTFS and Ext4.

Next I tweaked the mount options from within UDisks, so my `/etc/fstab` entry is  ***(EDIT-1)***:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/TW_db-bin /mnt/TW_db-bin auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=TW-db-bin,x-gvfs-icon=TW-db-bin 0
```

***EDIT-2***:
In UDisks, after successfully FAT re-formatting, I had:

```
Partition type: W95, FAT32(LBA)   # (*)
Content: FAT (16-bit version)
```

*(*) LBA mapping is late W95 FAT format style, i.e. total overkill on 128 MB SD media*

Last I tried to mount it with the following result:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/mmcblk0p1: Command-line
`mount "/mnt/TW_db-bin"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount:
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mmcblk0p1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

`dmesg | tail -f` only gives me `ufw` related stuff.

Re. "Wrong fs type" per the chatty err mesg above... presumably because I used FAT-16 bit (FAT32 LBA)...

***EDIT-3***:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 125 MB, 125960192 bytes
8 heads, 32 sectors/track, 961 cylinders, total 246016 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1              97      246015      122959+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I first tried Ext4 but ran into a formating error. Then I tried NTFS it mounted. **Question:** Is a FAT-16bit (FAT32 LBA) fs out of bound for Ubuntu 14.04 ?

=======================================================

***EDIT-4***:
Apparently in `gnome-disk-utility 3.10.0` (UDisks), you're outaluck when you want to format and mount a FAT SD32 LBA, as well as specify *"Show in user interface". That corresponds to the mount option: `x-gvfs-show`. Taking that out as well as:

```
- not specifying a label to mount on, such as `/mnt/foobar`

- not specifying an icon name (`x-gvfs-icon=foobar`)

- not specifying a display name (`x-gvfs-name=foobar`)
```

seems to solve the pbm. **BUT WHY ?**

Comment: How did you format it? Could you post full mount setup?

Comment: @Sneetsher: to reformat, I used UDisks' `format` in "More actions" submenu. For my `/etc/fstab` entry see EDIT in my post. Tx.

Comment: FAT should not be a problem. Can you mount using the mount command manually withouth the myriad of options?

Comment: I just tried same setup as yours, and it does work well. Could you post output of  `sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0`

Comment: @azzid: bingo ! something wrong with my "myriad" of mount options. It mounted auto and manually just fine without them. So something in: `nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=TW-db-bin,x-gvfs-icon=TW-db-bin,x-gvfs-symbolic-icon=TW-db-bin `is either wrong or creates a conflict. I'll be looking....

Comment: @Sneetsher: result of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/dev/mmcblk0p1` in ***EDIT-3***.

Comment: @Cbhihe, I'm looking for `/dev/mmcblk0` , not `/dev/mmcblk0p1`

Comment: @Sneetsher: Opps too fast - see ***EDIT-4***.

Comment: It seems related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/302458/vfat-partition-cannot-be-mounted-with-x-gvfs-show-option . Try this from bug report #22 `comment=x-gvfs-show` instead of `x-gvfs-show`

Comment: Absolutely ! Open bug. Thanks @Sneetsher and +1 !    It took a good two hours of my life of tinkering around to find out ! Case closed.  I will mark it as duplicate.

Comment: :) don't forget to up vote the  answer from that question.  He deserve the +1